# What is the data.table way to mutate and filter a data frame

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data frame and dplyr method to filter and mutate:

```r
    library(tidyverse)
    infile <- "https://nopaste.me/view/raw/767f65cf" # this link will exist forever
    gene_list <- c("ITGAM","ARG1")
    dat <- read_delim(infile,delim=",", col_types = cols()) %>%
       mutate(log_TPM = log(TPM))  %>% 
       filter(gene_symbol %in% gene_list)
    dat
#> # A tibble: 236 × 5
#>    gene_symbol sample_id   TPM    category    log_TPM
#>          <chr>     <chr> <dbl>       <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1         ARG1   SPL_128  2.32 Medication-  0.8415672
#> 2        ITGAM   SPL_128 14.92 Medication-  2.7027026
#> 3         ARG1   SPL_129  1.14 Medication-  0.1310283
#> 4        ITGAM   SPL_129 17.49 Medication-  2.8616293
#> 5         ARG1   SPL_130  8.02 Medication-  2.0819384
#> 6        ITGAM   SPL_130  3.65 Medication-  1.2947272
#> 7         ARG1   SPL_131  0.81 Medication- -0.2107210
#> 8        ITGAM   SPL_131  1.81 Medication-  0.5933268
#> 9         ARG1   SPL_132  0.00 Medication-       -Inf
#> 10       ITGAM   SPL_132  1.41 Medication-  0.3435897
#> # ... with 226 more rows
```

In reality it contains around 5 million rows instead of 236 rows.
Using dplyr is incredibly slow. Whats the data.table way of doing it?

Comment: I think what you want is `setDT(dat)[gene_symbol %in% gene_list, log_TPM := log(TPM)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `data.table` approach would be:

```
library(data.table)
d <- read_delim(infile,delim=",", col_types = cols())

setDT(d)
d <- d[gene_symbol %in% gene_list, ][, log_TPM := log(TPM)]
```

Having said that, it doesn't really lead to any performance improvements, at least on my machine. Both take about half a second, which isn't surprising since some of the bottleneck is the `gene_symbol %in% gene_list` and (to a lesser extent) the `log(TPM)` statements.

```
# create a 7-million row version of the sample data
large_data <- purrr::map_df(1:20000, ~ d)
large_data_dt <- as.data.table(large_data)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  dplyr = large_data %>% 
    filter(gene_symbol %in% gene_list) %>%
    mutate(log_TPM = log(TPM)),
  dt = large_data_dt[gene_symbol %in% gene_list, ][, log_TPM := log(TPM)],
  times = 20
)
```

Results on my machine:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
 dplyr 364.2026 446.1865 494.3292 476.0633 533.4779 835.1898    20   a
    dt 385.1917 448.6515 550.0030 492.5638 592.3481 946.6732    20   a
```

What do you mean by "incredibly slow"? Are you sure it's not another step that is slow?

Answer (score 2):

The `data.table` version of the command should be

```
require(data.table)
infile <- "https://nopaste.me/view/raw/767f65cf"
gene_list <- c("ITGAM","ARG1")
dat <- fread(infile)
dat <- dat[gene_symbol %in% gene_list]
dat[,log_TPM := log(TPM)]
```

Let me know if it helps.